# How to find out the country of the user's SIM card on Android?

Tags: android, country, sim-card

Is there a way to check what is the user's country? "Locale" isn't good enough because there are plenty of English locales but they are spread all over the world.

Maybe somehow with **IMEI** or...?

So actually I need to find out which country does the **SIM card** belong to?

EDIT: GPS or internet **are not allowed**.

Comment: That's a vague question. Do you mean the user's country of birth, of residence, or simply their current location?

Comment: Their current location - but without GPS or internet.

Comment: IMEI is just the equipment identifier. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()
```

More info [Android documentation - TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).

Edit: Depends what you are looking for. IMEI may not be relevant as the phone might have been ordered/bought from another country or the user might be in another country when using it. Also I don't know if the IMEI tells you the actual contry the device is being sold in, but rather the country of the manufacturer (not sure on this one though).

Comment: If it must be from the SIM card (which presumes the phone and network use a SIM card), might `TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso()` be better?  Also, if only resources need to be customized, there's a resource directory qualifier for the MCC.

Comment: Again, it depends what you are looking for. If you want to get the originating country or it's real position. SIM Country ISO will get you the originating country, but what will you get from it when the user is abroad using Roaming? You won't get it's current position this way, just the country where he bought the SIM. But if this is what you're interested in, then I think it'll work. :)